# Rabin-Miller-Prime test

Tags: c++

It runs perfectly but when the numbers are 6 digits and more it "crashes". I have no idea why it doesn't work. I also haven't tried a lot of things to fix it because i don't no where to begin. I know, the test has some weaknesses, I already did some research. There are certain numbers, that cant be detected by the test, but they should be filtered out, when you increase the accuracy

```
bool testPrime(int primenumber_1)
{
    bool even_number_checker = false;
    bool prime;
    int counter = 0;
    int primenumber_mod = 0;
    int variable_1 = 1;
    int variable_2 = 1;
    primenumber_mod = primenumber_1 - 1;
    if(primenumber_1 % 2 == 0) return false;
    while(primenumber_mod%2 == 0)
    {
        primenumber_mod/=2;
    }
    if(even_number_checker == false && primenumber_1        != 43405 && primenumber_1 != 27905)
    {
        variable_1 = (int)pow(2, primenumber_mod) % primenumber_1;
        if(variable_1 != 1 && variable_1 != -1)
        {
            while(variable_1 + 1 != primenumber_1 &&
                  variable_1 - 1 != primenumber_1 &&
                  variable_2 + 1 != primenumber_1 &&
                  variable_2 -1 != primenumber_1)
            {                
                if(counter >= 40) break;
                variable_2 = (int)pow(variable_1, 2) % primenumber_1;
                variable_1 = variable_2;
                counter++;
            }
            prime = (variable_1 + 1 == primenumber_1 ||
                     variable_2 + 1 == primenumber_1);
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

int primeGenerator()
{
    int number = rand()%999900+100000;
    while(!testPrime(number))
    {
        number = rand()%899000+100000;
    }
    return number;
}

bool testPrimeSafe(int number)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if(number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void testTestPrime()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        int prime = primeGenerator();
        if(testPrimeSafe(prime))
        {
            std::cout << "\e[32;42mSUCCESS :: " << prime << "\e[0m\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\e[48;5;196;1m*EVIL MORTY THEME PLAYING* :: " << prime << "\e[0m\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    testTestPrime();
}
```

Comment: Ensure that your data types can hold the requested input values.

Comment: `pow` is never a good choice for integers.

Comment: Oh yeah thank you this makes sense. Because when they square the number gets over the int limit. Thank you for your quick help!

Comment: "_I also haven't tried a lot of things to fix it because i don't no where to begin._": You start by using a debugger (search for the canonical debugger for the compiler you are using and a tutorial on how to use said debugger), then you use it to step through your code and observe the values of variables until it crashes. From the information you gather in this way you should then try to deduce whatever logic or other issue your code has. If at any particular point in the program execution something doesn't make sense to you and a search doesn't answer it, then ask here with a [mre] about it.

Comment: I already got a answer from Yksisarvinen, and btw my question wasn't how i could find the problem by my self, but thank you anyway i guess. The debugger wasn't the right way to go on this problem because i already knew whats not working i just didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: You should post your fix as answer. As is the code should neither crash nor work.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `(int)pow(2, primenumber_mod)` will overflow a signed 32-bit integer if `primenumber_mod` is greater than 31. If the input is a 6-digit integer it is very likely `primenumber_mod` will be much larger than that.